# Optmize logic IF statement

Tags: c++, performance

I have a little dilema with such if statement, I have tried optimizing it in order to remove some checks, but could not think of how to make this code part cleaner. Can someone please make a review, and tell if it's possible to optimize such statement of maybe there is some law for this? Thank you

```
//letter = 'E' or 'R' ( char )
//second letter = 'Q' or 'A' ( char )
//DoFlip = false or true ( bool )

if((letter == 'E' && secondLetter == 'Q' && DoFlip == false)    || 
       (letter == 'E' && secondLetter == 'A' && DoFlip == true) ||
       (letter == 'R' && secondLetter == 'Q' && DoFlip == false)||
       (letter == 'R' && secondLetter == 'A' && DoFlip== true))
    {
      //DoSmth here
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to code review. This question is off topic because there isn't enough code to review. It might be better to ask it on stackoverflow.com, but try searching stackoverflow first to see if it has been answered already.

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, this can be rewritten as:

```
if(((letter == 'E' || letter == 'R')&& secondLetter == 'Q' && DoFlip == false)|| 
   ((letter == 'E' || letter == 'R') && secondLetter == 'A' && DoFlip == true)
    {
      //DoSmth here
    }
```

According to distributive law -

```
A && B || A && C = (B || C) && A
```

In your logic - (letter == 'E' || letter == 'R') can take place of A with (secondLetter == 'Q' && DoFlip == false) as B and (secondLetter == 'A' && DoFlip == true) as C.

So your logic can be simplified to -

```
if((letter == 'E' || letter == 'R') && 
   ((secondLetter == 'Q' && DoFlip == false) || 
   (secondLetter == 'A' && DoFlip == true))
```